# How do I process my LiveMeeting recording into an actual video?

Tags: video, audio, media, live-meeting

I finished up a LiveMeeting that I recorded. However, when I saved it, it saved everything to a folder with everything separated out. IE: There's an audio file with no video, there's a video file with no audio, and some other random files and folders including a *.trd file at the root directory.

This seems like a kluge and is very weird to me. How do I merge all this into a video that has audio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft makes a Recording Convertor for Live Meeting 2007 application that should do this.

> Recording Converter for Microsoft Office Live Meeting 2007 is a tool for Office Live Meeting 2007 customers to convert recorded meetings in High Fidelity Presentation (HFP) format into single movie files. The converted movie files can be integrated with a customer's existing learning management system, and edited by using a video editing tool such as Windows Movie Maker, and then viewed on portable devices.
>
> Supported Operating Systems: Windows XP or higher
>
> Live Meeting Requirements: Live Meeting 2007
>
> Application Requirements: .NET Framework 2.0, Windows Media Player 9 or higher

Find more feature and usage details at their product home page.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/live-meeting-help/recording-converter-for-microsoft-office-live-meeting-2007-HA010121597.aspx